# Anonymous field as pointer or embed

Tags: go

What is the different between anonymous field as pointer or anonymous field as usual. Consider, how I embed Foo into Bar struct.

Look at the following code snippet:

First with anonymous field as pointer

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct{}

func (*Foo) Run() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}

type Bar struct {
    *Foo
}

func main() {
    bar := new(Bar)
    bar.Run() 
}
```

and second anonymous field as usual:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct{}

func (*Foo) Run() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}

type Bar struct {
    Foo
}

func main() {
    bar := new(Bar)
    bar.Run()
}
```

What is different between them?

Update:
I pick up this sample from [revel webframework](http://revel.github.io/tutorial/requestflow.html), how they extend a custom controller. Look at this code snippet

```
type App struct {
    *revel.Controller
}
```

why do revel use pointer to embed controller struct. What is the sense of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that `Foo` is an empty struct, embedding it in `Bar` will make no change to to the memory footprint of `Bar`.

However, embedding a *pointer* to `Foo` will change `Bar`; it will add a pointer value, initialized to `nil`. If the only purpose of `Foo` is to have methods, then using a pointer is superfluous.

Of course, were you to add some fields into `Foo`, then, in the pointer case, you'd also need to add `bar.Foo = new(Foo)` into main, or else you'll have problems.

The advantage of using a pointer would be that you could share the same `Foo` instance between multiple instances of `Bar`, or else you could keep it `nil` until you really need it.

The disadvantage would be that it would be slightly more trouble, and slightly less efficient, if there's always a 1-to-1 `Foo`-to-`Bar` mapping.

Comment: `Foo instance between multiple instances of Bar` how can I do that. Do you have some sample?

Comment: @zero_coding Given `bar2.Foo = bar1.Foo`, where `Foo` is a pointer type, then both `bar1` and `bar2` will point to the same instance of `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it forms valid selector there is no difference in usage except the following ( and the usual tradeoffs of using values vs. pointers ) :

> - If x is of pointer type and has the value nil and x.f denotes a struct field, assigning to or evaluating x.f causes a run-time panic.
> - If x is of interface type and has the value nil, calling or evaluating the method x.f causes a run-time panic.

and this :

> - If S contains an anonymous field T, the method sets of S and *S both
>     include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also
>     includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
> - If S contains an anonymous field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods
>     with receiver T or *T.